# Isotope rows collapsing in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery-isotope

So, I'm having some issues with Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co) on my site I'm developing in IE8.

Basically, all the columns are getting the right width, but not the right height (overlapping). I'm using the imagesLoaded thing and it's still not fixing it.

Here is a screen shot of what it's coming out as
[image: IE8 Isotope screenshot]

Here is my the HTML structure of one of the "boxes":

```
<div class="example-site professional-packages online-shop" data-build-type="professional-packages" data-example-id="203"">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="glass icon">l</div>
    </div>
    <img align="middle" src="/files/cache/3ed224bb16fe1239899118ac683ea7cc_f184.jpg" alt="www.www.rainline.co.nz">
</div>
```

And here is my JS:

```
var  $container;
$(function(){
    $container = $('#example-sites-container');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.example-site',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 307,
            gutter: 19
        }
    });
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope('layout');
    });
});
```

Hopefully someone can help me with this as I'm stuck

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue for this. Basically IE8 and Isotope don't like working with EM's for height. As soon as I changed it to pixels, all was fixed.